# Populating an array from a txt file in C++

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty populating an array from a .txt file. I can do it without the while loop if I already know the size of the file. However, once I incorporate a while loop to extract the file size the input odes not configure correctly. Pleas take a look over my code an let me know if you see where I am going wrong.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    const char *inName_1 = "Instance_1.txt";
    const char *inName_2 = "Instance_2.txt";
    int arraySize_1 = 0, arraySize_2 = 0;
    int array_1[20];
    int array_2[20];
    int number;

    ifstream A2_file_1(inName_1);

    if (A2_file_1.fail())
    {
        cout << "File 1 not open!" << '\n';
    }

    while (!A2_file_1.eof())
    {
        arraySize_1++;
        A2_file_1 >> number;
    }

    if (A2_file_1.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize_1; i++)
        {
            A2_file_1 >> array_1[i];
        }

        A2_file_1.close();
    }

    cout << "The size of the array 1 is: " << arraySize_1 << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize_1; i++)
    {
        cout << array_1[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: As another problem, once the first loop is over, the file is beyond the end. What do you then think happens when you attempt to read from it?

Comment: Alternatively you can use the stringbuffer `#include <sstream> std::stringstream buffer << file.rdbuf(); string fileContents = buffer.str();`

Comment: After counting you are at EOF. How many numbers can you read from that position?

Comment: And if you don't know the number of value in the file beforehand, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Together with [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) filling that vector with numbers from the file is a *single line*.

Comment: Use std::vector and push_back.

Answer (score 0):

To read an arbitrary amount of numeric values from a text-file, all you need is an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and a couple of [`std::istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) objects.

Then is as simple as

```
std::ifstream input("Instance_1.txt");

std::vector<int> values(std::istreambuf_iterator<int>(input),
                        std::istreambuf_iterator<int>());
```

That's it. Those four lines of code (counting the empty line) will read all `int` values from the text file `Instance_1.txt` and place them into the vector `values`.